# Ramda - How to map object values to string

Tags: ramda.js

I am trying to use Ramda to get `x,y` coordinates to draw `polyline` in `svg`.

I have `edge` object which contains all the points I need and it looks like this:

```
const edge = {
    "id": "e1_s0",
    "startPoint": {
        "x": 212,
        "y": 505.33333333333326
    },
    "endPoint": {
        "x": 232,
        "y": 302
    },
    "bendPoints": [
        {
            "x": 222,
            "y": 505.33333333333326
        },
        {
            "x": 222,
            "y": 302
        }
    ],
    "incomingShape": "n1",
    "outgoingShape": "n2"
}
```

I tried to use Ramda to get `x, y` from `startPoint`, `endPoint` and `bendPoints`. I came up with this piece of code:

```
R.pipe(
  R.pick(['bendPoints', 'endPoint', 'startPoint']),
  R.values,
  R.flatten,
  R.sortBy(R.prop('x'))
)(edge)
```

Here you can check it in [ramda editor](https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20edge%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22e1_s0%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22startPoint%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22x%22%3A%20212%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22y%22%3A%20505.33333333333326%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22endPoint%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22x%22%3A%20232%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22y%22%3A%20302%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22bendPoints%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22x%22%3A%20222%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22y%22%3A%20505.33333333333326%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22x%22%3A%20222%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22y%22%3A%20302%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22incomingShape%22%3A%20%22n1%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22outgoingShape%22%3A%20%22n2%22%0A%7D%0A%0A%0AR.pipe%28%0A%20%20R.pick%28%5B%27bendPoints%27%2C%20%27endPoint%27%2C%20%27startPoint%27%5D%29%2C%0A%20%20R.values%2C%0A%20%20R.flatten%2C%0A%20%20R.sortBy%28R.prop%28%27x%27%29%29%0A%29%28edge%29%0A%0A%0A%0A)

As a result, I get:

```
[
    {
        x: 212,
        y: 505.33333333333326
    },
    {
        x: 222,
        y: 505.33333333333326
    },
    {
        x: 222,
        y: 302
    },
    {
        x: 232,
        y: 302
    }
]
```

But I need a string with `x` and `y` pairs divided by space and I have no idea how to proceed to get to that point: `212,505.33333333333326 222,505.33333333333326 222,302 232,302`

Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT: complete solution**

```
R.pipe(
  R.pick(['bendPoints', 'endPoint', 'startPoint']),
  R.values,
  R.flatten,
  R.sortBy(R.prop('x')),
  R.map(
    R.pipe(
      R.props(['x', 'y']),
      R.join(',')
    )
  ),
  R.join(" ")
)(edge)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the steps you need are:

- For each point,

  - Take the `x` and `y` values, and
  - Join those in to a single string, separated by `","`
- Take those strings and join them in to a single string, separated by `" "`

Which can be translated to ramda quite literally:

```js
const formatPoints = pipe(
  map(
    pipe(
      props(["x", "y"]),
      join(",")
    )
  ),
  join(" ")
);
```

Comment: Thank you :). This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this works with `bendPoints` as an array.

Comment: @customcommander This code only works with the OPs current output (which is a flat list of `{ x, y }` points). Since they already got quite far I didn't see the need to rewrite that first part   Do you think I should edit my answer to include the complete flow?

Comment: Oh I see! Yeah I thought you were feeding `edge` to that function but you're only applying it to the result of the other function. It wasn't obvious tbh. Up to you.

Comment: @customcommander I edited the original question and added the completed flow. Maybe it is not pretty but works like a charm :)